# encoding the contents of an xslt variable including the tags

Tags: xslt, base64, xslt-2.0

I want to encode a soap request before sending it to server. textToBase64 is a custom function in a library.

```
<xsl:value-of select="codecs:textToBase64($MyRequest)"/>
```

However the output of the textTobase64 function truncates the tags and encodes only the data.

1. How can I convert the variable to string
   OR
2. tell the function to not strip the tags.

The variable is a result tree fragment like

```
<xsl:variable name="MyRequest">
 <soap:ENVELOPE>
  <!--....-->
 </soap:ENVELOPE>
</variable>
```

Comment: BTW: I am dealing with XSLT 2.0. It is Saxon HE implementation.

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense to me. What variable do you refer to in your first point, and what do you mean exactly by converting it to string? And how are we supposed to know the answer to the second point since the function is custom?

Comment: @MathiasMüller you can trust I'm quite familiar with XSLT, just not in the context ot the purpose you mention.

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester No offense intended. I'll delete my comment in a moment, then.

Comment: @MathiasMüller None taken, I accept the fact that my question may have looked naive since I wasn't familiar with this particular usage of XSLT. No need to delete your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really use an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 then the variable created as

```
<xsl:variable name="MyRequest">
 <soap:ENVELOPE>
  <!--....-->
 </soap:ENVELOPE>
</variable>
```

is not a result tree fragment as there are no result tree fragments in XSLT 2.0, it is rather simply a temporary document tree. If you want to serialize a document tree to a string with markup then you either have to consider using the commercial editions of Saxon 9 as they provide an extension function http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!functions/saxon/serialize in XSLT 2.0 or a built-in function http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!functions/fn/serialize in XSLT 3.0 so you could use `codecs:textToBase64(saxon:serialize($myRequest, 'someOutputName'))` respectively  `codecs:textToBase64(serialize($myRequest))` or you need to write the serialization in XSLT respectively use library doing that, like http://lenzconsulting.com/xml-to-string/.

Answer (score 0):

(Martin Honnen has already given a very helpful answer - you should accept it. I would like to add something to it.)

Perhaps it is also worth saying that `textToBase64` cannot process anything else than simple strings. If it is handed a variable containing a temporary document, it most likely encodes the concatenation of all text nodes.

> However the output of the textTobase64 function truncates the tags and
>   encodes only the data.

The function does not exactly "truncate" the tags, the concept of tags is unknown to an XSLT processor. In other words, it sees an element not as `<x>`(where "x" is the element name), but as an element node, an abstract entity. It's just that this function does not expect element nodes as an argument.